# Creating address book from all H-Mart locations

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the [H-Mart webpage](https://www.hmart.com/ourstores) to pull all the addresses and create a spreadsheet out of it.

What I have so far is the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests
import html5lib
import os
import io
import sys

url = 'https://www.hmart.com/ourstores'
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,'cp437','backslashreplace')
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features = 'html.parser')
#soup = BeautifulSoup(page, features = 'html.parser').encode('utf-8')
text = soup.get_text()
soup = soup.prettify()

stores = soup.find('div', {'class':'stores-list'})

print(stores)
```

However, my latest code has generated the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\mypath\myscript.py", line 18, in <module>
    stores = soup.find('div', {'class':'stores-list'})
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

An example of some html from the webpage that I want to scrape is the following (but you can also click the hyperlink to see the full html).

```
       <div class="stores-list">
        <div class="store-item">
         <strong>
          California
         </strong>
         <ul class="clearer">
          <li>
           <a class="store-name" href="https://www.hmart.com/storelocator/index/index/id/59/" title="Arcadia">
            Arcadia
           </a>
           <span class="restaurant">
            <img alt="restaurant" src="https://www.hmart.com/static/version1588680879/frontend/Eguana/hmart/en_US/Kensium_Storelocator/images/location/ico-food-court.png"/>
           </span>
          </li>
```

I did notice some json stuff within the full html that could (?) give me the data I'm looking for much easily, but I have no idea how to scrape it to the fullest capability. Any suggestions to make this code work and to make this spreadsheet created would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove `soup = soup.prettify()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = urlopen('https://www.hmart.com/ourstores')

data = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")

for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class':"store-item"}):
    state = i.find("strong").text

    for store in i.find_all("a", {"class": "store-name"}):
        data.append({"state": state, "location": store.text.strip()})

print(pd.DataFrame(data))
```